# Is there a way to get joined tables as array?

Tags: mysql, arrays, join

I have a user table, education table and work experience table:

**users**

- id
- first_name
- last_name

**education**

- user_id
- name
- start_year
- end_year

**workexperience**

- user_id
- name
- start_year
- end_year

Now I want to get a nice overview of all education and work experience of a person.

When using regular joins, I will get a lot of rows, since the number of educations and work experiences will multiply the number of rows.

The best case would be if I get the id, first_name and last_name only once, with another array inside with the educations and work experiences.

Could anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: [Subquery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html), i.e. SELECT in SELECT

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT` (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) is what you're looking for, i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `GROUP BY` like

```
SELECT users.*,
       workexperience.*,
       education.start_year as EDU_start_year,education.end_year as EDU_end_year
FROM users
JOIN education ON education.user_id = users.id
JOIN workexperience ON workexperience.user_id = users.id
GROUP BY id,first_name,last_name
```

You can group by `id` itself also.